# Finding the current name of the model being used in a class based view, then using it as one of two filter parameters

Tags: python, django, model, backend

My problem is that I am trying to find the name of the model currently being used in the Class based Detail View, then using that name as one of two search parameters (The Model used in the class based view is a foreign key of another model I'm trying to filter)

I can't figure out how to find out how to filter by the current model being used.

Here is my models.py

```
class MyProjects(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140)

class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    project = models.ForeignKey(MyProjects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
```

And here is my views.py

```
class ProjectView(DetailView):
    model = MyProjects


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        CurrentProject = get_object_or_404(MyProjects, title=self.kwargs['MyProjects'])
        completed = Post.objects.filter(status='Completed', project= CurrentProject)
        inProgress = Post.objects.filter(status='InProgress', project= CurrentProject)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(project= CurrentProject)
        Features = Post.objects.filter(ticket_type='Features', project= CurrentProject)

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts '] = posts 
        context['Features '] = Features 
        context['completed '] = completed 
        context['inProgress '] = inProgress 
        context['projects'] = projects


        return context
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with "name of the model"?, what is the filter condition you need it for?

Comment: @cabesuon I am building a task completion queue. Basically people can add projects, then people can add "tickets" to that project. For example I could create "Project 1" and people could start adding Tasks of things that need to get done for that project What I'm trying to do right now is make a detail view for one project. I need to search for Posts specific to that object, and the other things I need to filter the tasks for, such as type and status.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using `DetailView` correctly, but you are in the good path.

It is important to remember that `self.object` references the object that the view is operating on. In your code you name it `CurrentProject`, so no need to query for the object, you already have it. In the general case, you pass the id of the object to the view as a parameter of the url.

Concluding...

I think the view should look something like this,

```py
class ProjectView(DetailView):
    model = MyProjects

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        completed = Post.objects.filter(status='Completed', project=self.object)
        in_progress = Post.objects.filter(status='InProgress', project=self.object)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(project=self.object)
        features = Post.objects.filter(ticket_type='Features', project=self.object)

        context['posts'] = posts 
        context['features'] = features 
        context['completed'] = completed 
        context['inProgress'] = in_progress 
        context['projects'] = projects

        return context
```

And, the url of the view should something like this,

```py
path('<int:pk>/', views.ProjectView.as_view(), name='project-detail')
```